# Docx library doesn't recognizes Document method

Tags: python

I'm trying to use docx library, but I'm getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Document'
```

This is my code:

```
import docx
document = docx.Document('file.docx')
```

What is happening? I already used document in other computers. I  installed docx library using pip:

```
pip install docx
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

your'e confusing package `docx` with the package `python-docx`.

```
pip install python-docx


>>> import docx
>>> docx.Document
<class 'docx.api.Document'>
```

But you are right the naming here is a problem.